# INNER JOIN with VARCHAR between two large tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join, bigdata

I'm trying to join two large tables using two VARCHAR(255) fields.

tbl1 got 100.000 rows - INNODB

tbl2 got 1.200.000 rows - INNODB

The column "artno" are indexed in both tables.

**My query looks like this:**

```
SELECT tbl1.id
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.artno = tbl1.artno AND tbl2.brand = tbl1.brand
```

This query takes about 20 seconds to run.

What´s the best way to join to tables on a VARCHAR?

Can I increase the performance for my query in any way?

Comment: the query is ok. You should create the correct indexes on your table.

Comment: And how should the indexes look like? At the moment a got two "single" indexes for artno in both tables.

Comment: Use `Explain`to find out which one you need. I think you need one for both column.

Comment: And give a look at [the Query Execution Plan docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/execution-plan-information.html) for each column meaning.

Answer (score 0):

May be best performed  with select index to use

I think it is for innoDB script as **USE INDEX (IDX_artno)**

```
SELECT tbl1.id
FROM tbl1  USE INDEX (IDX_artno) 
INNER JOIN tbl2 USE INDEX (IDX_artno) ON tbl2.artno = tbl1.artno AND tbl2.brand = tbl1.brand
```